# why my ASP.NET MVC Htmlhelper htmlAttributes cant work?

Tags: asp.net

When I user this targ on a page like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.JobName, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

It can work, But when I use like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.JobName, new { @data-provide="typeahead", })
```

then it can't work, because this attribute: data-provide, it have a symbol which is '-', how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Use `@data_provide`. This falls under C# nomenclature, so you have to work with what is allowed (within the language confines).

MVC builds in a work-around allowing you to supplement hyphens with underscores (which will be replaced when built as HTML).

This is the same reason you must use `@class` over simply class (keyword collision).